# My question is about indentation error in python spyder

Tags: python

Trying to implement K-NN in python on spyder IDE

```
for i in range(5):
    neighbors = get_neighbors(learnset_data, 
                              learnset_labels, 
                              testset_data[i], 
                              3, 
                              distance=distance)
    print(i,testset_data[i],testset_labels[i],neighbors)

from collections import Counter
def vote(neighbors):
    class_counter = Counter()
    for neighbor in neighbors:
        class_counter[neighbor[2]] += 1
    return class_counter.most_common(1)[0][0]
#We will test 'vote' on our training samples:
    for i in range(n_training_samples):
    neighbors = get_neighbors(learnset_data,learnset_labels,testset_data[i],3,distance=distance)
    print("index: ", i,", result of vote: ", vote(neighbors),", label: ", testset_labels[i],", data: ", testset_data[i])
```

> File
>   "C:\Users\TAGORE\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/TAGORE/Desktop/pyt/nn1.py", line 119
>       neighbors = get_neighbors(learnset_data,learnset_labels,testset_data[i],3,distance=distance)
>               ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: you forgot the identations on line `get_neighbors(learnset_data,learnset_labels,testset_data[i],3,distance=distance)`

Comment: I think you added indentation on line `for i in range(n_training_samples):` when there shouldn't be any

Comment: Your code is very hard to read, you need to put empty lines after the import section, and after every function definition.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis: don't edit out the OP's wrong indentation, that's the whole point of the question :) I reverted your edit #3

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to indent your line in the 'for' loop, and wrongly indented your 'for' loop after the 'return' statement.

```
for i in range(5):
    neighbors = get_neighbors(learnset_data, 
                              learnset_labels, 
                              testset_data[i], 
                              3, 
                              distance=distance)
    print(i,testset_data[i],testset_labels[i],neighbors)

from collections import Counter
def vote(neighbors):
    class_counter = Counter()
    for neighbor in neighbors:
        class_counter[neighbor[2]] += 1
    return class_counter.most_common(1)[0][0]
#We will test 'vote' on our training samples:
for i in range(n_training_samples):
    neighbors = get_neighbors(learnset_data,learnset_labels,testset_data[i],3,distance=distance)
    print("index: ", i,", result of vote: ", vote(neighbors),", label: ", testset_labels[i],", data: ", testset_data[i])
```